# Spring Boot / @Transactional is working in Standalone-Mode, but not in Glassfish

Tags: java, spring-boot, jakarta-ee, glassfish, payara

I have a Service (JHipster4) that uses JPA Repositories to manipulate a Postgres database. That Service is importing an CSV and creating a lot of entities. The public method that creates the entities is annotated with @Transactional (import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional)

When starting the application stand-alone (bootRun, OpenJDK 1.8, internal tomcat server), the Import is running fast with 700 entities/s. As soon as the import finishes, i can see the data appearing in the database at once. This makes me confident that the transaction is working correctly.

As soon as i deploy my Application to payara 4.1, the @Transactional annotation does not seem to work like it did before. I can see the database being populated line by line and the rate is slow (20 entities/s), just like without @Transactional.

Within my import, i truncate the database tables using the entityManager and createNativeQuery(..).executeUpdate();

If i remove the @Transactional, i get

`javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete`

which is fine. On glassfish with @Transactional i do not get such an error (which is fine too) but it does not look like there is a transaction running from the database's point of view (entities slowly populating).

The payara configuration is completely default. spring database configuration is also minimal, com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource, database-platform: io.github.jhipster.domain.util.FixedPostgreSQL82Dialect, database: POSTGRESQL.

on the beans.xml i have set bean-discovery-mode="none" because CDI gave me problems.

So what is the major difference of using Spring Boot JPA in a stand-alone context and in an application container (glassfish)?

Why is @Transactional not working like on the stand-alone version? Can you explain what is going on and how to resolve?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

When running within a application server environment, the application server supplies an EntityManager to the application. When running standalone, the EntityManager comes from spring. That means that if the Application runs within glassfish, the glassfish manages the transactions.

As the Glassfisch transaction manager does not understand the Spring's @Transactional annotation, it does not have an effect.

Option 1 is to change your Code to use the application servers transaction API. i did not want to do that, because i would loose the ability to run standalone (for tests i.e.).

Option 2 is to implement your own EntityManager, TransactionManager and DataSource, like this. My goal was to create an drop-in-replacement of the default TransactionManager, which reads the spring boot configuration.

```
@Configuration
public class EntityManagerConfiguration {

    protected final static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EntityManagerConfiguration.class);

    private final ConfigurableEnvironment env;

    @Autowired
    public EntityManagerConfiguration(ConfigurableEnvironment env) {
        this.env = env;
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManager() {

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(dataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan(
                "com.project.domain"
        );

        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        HashMap<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put("hibernate.physical_naming_strategy", SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy.class.getName());
        properties.put("hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy", SpringImplicitNamingStrategy.class.getName());
        Map<String,Object> props = ConfigAccessService.getPropertiesStartingWith(
                env,
                "spring.jpa.properties"
        );

        for(Map.Entry<String,Object> config : props.entrySet()) {
            String configName = config.getKey().replace("spring.jpa.properties.","");
            properties.put(configName, config.getValue());
            log.info("setting " + configName + " = " + config.getValue());
        }
        em.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);
        log.info("EntitiyManager configured");

        return em;
    }

    /**
     * as we want to run stand-alone (tests) and in glassfish(JavaEE) the same, we setup our own connection
     * using the Hikari Connection-Pooling.
     * @return
     */
    @Primary
    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource(){
        HikariConfig hikariConfig = new HikariConfig();
        hikariConfig.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        hikariConfig.setJdbcUrl(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.url"));
        hikariConfig.setUsername(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.username"));
        hikariConfig.setPassword(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.password"));

        hikariConfig.setMaximumPoolSize(10);
        hikariConfig.setConnectionTestQuery("SELECT 1");
        hikariConfig.setPoolName("springHikariCP");

        HikariDataSource dataSource = new HikariDataSource(hikariConfig);

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {

        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager
                = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(
                entityManager().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }


}
```